# Loading record in datagridview though sqldataadapter

Tags: c#

I need to load data from sql database to datagridview in windows form application using c#. I am new in development and have no idea.Please help me ,Thanks in advnace

Comment: Start by googling. There are thousands of examples and tutorials available. Come back when you tried something and get stuck - and then ask a **specific** question. Right now your question is far to broad to be answered in StackOverflow format.

Comment: Unclear. Need more Information. Provide codes you have tired and tell errors you get?

Comment: i got solution from google thanks